# Flask POST request page error: page not found

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a simple web application with flask.
I have this code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

# create the Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

users = {'Vladimir': 100}

@app.route('/balance', methods = ['POST'])
def getbalance():
    bal = request.args.get('bal')
    return(users[bal])
    
@app.route('/register', methods = ['POST'])
def newcc():
    # if key doesn't exist, returns None
    nick = request.args.get('nick')
    if nick in users.keys():
        return 'User already exists'
    else:
        users[nick] = 0
        return 'Account created successfully!'
```

When I request page with `domain.com/register?nick=Mike` it returns `404 not found` error, please, help

Comment: show your whole code?

Comment: Whole code: https://pastebin.com/UJ8jJRaq

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There must be something missing from your example code. I ran it with basic boilerplate for Flask and it works fine. So the problem is not in the code you shared in pastebin.

Comment: I can not reproduce the error. Run your code under `localhost:5000` and it works for me. What code are you using to access the endpoint?

Comment: OK, thanks, fixed. Now I am getting another error: 500 while accessing /balance page

Comment: When you say "I request page...", how are you making that request? Are you doing this in a browser? Or with curl or some other HTTP client? Or something else?

Comment: @AnnetteHirsch a 500 error means there is an error in your code. If you are running the code on your local machine, you should look at the console where it is running. There will be a stacktrace which tells you what the full error is.

Comment: Python post request to domain.com/register?nick=Sam and then post request to domain.com/balance?bal=Sam

Comment: Your `getbalance` function returns an integer which is not an allowed return type for view functions.

Comment: methods = ['GET','POST'] do this and run with localhost